# Cloudify: No default VPC for this user

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, cloudify

I'm going trough Cloudify documentation and trying to deploy it in our AWS

I did checkout latest code of Cloudify Manager Blueprint from [GitHub](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-manager-blueprints)

Updated *inputs.yaml* file and when i run it with command:

```
cfy bootstrap -p aws-ec2-manager-blueprint.yaml -i inputs.yaml --task-retries 10
```

It passing all validation steps, generating keys, security groups and then throw me a lot of errors of:

```
NonRecoverableError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Code>VPCIdNotSpecified</Code>
            <Message>No default VPC for this user</Message>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
    <RequestID>some-blah-blah-blah</RequestID>
</Response>
```

Could anyone please suggest where, in which config under which tag should I specify VPS I want to use? 
Nor I didnt find anything in AWS AMI how to set default VPC per specific user - as I did created Cloudify-bot service account with access key

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding Default VPC and Subnets:
If you deleted your default VPC and created your own custom VPC with SubNets you cant make it Default.
Here is a Quote from [official AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html#deleting-default-vpc):

> You cannot mark an existing VPC as a default VPC. If you delete a default subnet and then need to restore it, create a new subnet in your default VPC, and then contact AWS Support to mark the subnet as a default subnet.

Regarding Cloudify and custom VPC handling:
It seems that custom VPC handling is available trough "AWS VPC Plugin" which belong only to [Pro version](http://getcloudify.org/goPro.html) - pay version, not Open Source. What is more it is marked to be included only in Cloudify v3.3 - current one is v3.2 - so it seems not ready yet

Answer (score 7):

As Google brought me here as the top answer in May 2019 I'm confirming what David Resnick points to above.
[Creating a default VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc)

[image: create Default VPN]

Comment: This answer may seem simple, but it took me forever to discover it. Thanks JohnC!

Answer (score 1):

It seems functionality has changed. In December 2017, I ran into "No Default VPC for user" when creating EC2 machine with packer. I was able to create a new VPC from the AWS console, under VPC's. There was a button "Create Default VPC". I pressed it, and viola - I could create machines again.

Comment: After 3 years? Check the dates, I rised the question in 2015 and it was the way it was, even specifically documented as it is.

Comment: The feature to create a default VPC was added in July 2017. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/create-a-new-default-vpc-using-aws-console-or-cli/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is no default VPC allocated. Googling I found this:

"If you created your AWS account after 2013-12-04, it supports only EC2-VPC. In this case, you'll have a default VPC in each AWS region."

Seems you might need to create a new VPC and assign it as the default.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/getting-started-create-vpc.html

Comment: That is the problem! Yes we had default VPC but we deleted all of them and create our own with own SubNets to match our Global network infrastructure and IP ranges.
However I cant find a way how to set any custom created VPC nor SubNet to default. In fact in the Console in list there is Column called "Default VPC" or "Default Subnet" and for each one it says "No" and I cant find any way how to set it to "Yes" to one of them

Maybe this functionality available only trough CLI and not trough Web Console? Then what is command?